# How to Display Best Sellers dynamic specific category?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

how to display Best sellers dynmaic and specific category in magento 1.6.2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display Bestseller you can load the collection of products from resource model reports like below

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'short_description', 'description')) //edit to suit tastes
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); //best sellers on top
```

and to load them category wise you can get the current category or pass it harcoded. and just you need to filter the product in that category.

Comment: I am Magento Begnner.I want to display the Best Seller for Specific Category in List Page In Magento 1.6.2.0 ? Thnks Girish Anand

Comment: Okay you can check with this extension (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bestseller-selected-on-category-id.html)... To show as list page you need to create module for that... you can add me on girish.anand85@gmail.com  i will help u there

Comment: Hi.i have use silder in magento, in all browser runnig silder but ie8 has not working silder. i have use the noconflict in scrpit. plz help me

Comment: I already sent you the code in your mail box... let me know if its working or not....

Comment: Old post, but things move on, and stuff gets better with time. So to help others finding this post, I'd like to mention one of my extensions, which allows creation of Best Sellers (and much much more) dynamic categories. It is aptly named: Magento Dynamic category Products. http://www.proxiblue.com.au/magento-dynamic-category-products.html